# Event.target types for name input in FromHandler with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, eventhandler

I have a simple form in a React SPA with typescript.

I'm going to make this form processing simple, without adding component state and so, just to get value from the named input, name = 'gameId'.

There are two ways I've tried in the example below:

1. If I use event.target, TS says the "children" doesn't exist on type 'EventTarget'
2. If I use event.currentTarget, TS says the "gameId" doesn't exist on type 'HTMLCollection'.

Is there any way to solve these?

```
const submitAcceptGameHandler: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // 1st
  // Property 'children' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)
  const inputData = event.target.children.gameId.value;

  // 2nd
  // Property 'gameId' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollection'.ts(2339)
  const inputData = event.currentTarget.children.gameId.value;
  
    console.log(inputData);
  };
```

```
<form onSubmit={submitAcceptGameHandler}>
  <button type="submit">ACCEPT GAME</button>
  <input name="gameId" type="text" placeholder={'Input game id...'}></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Cast (assert) `event.target` to `HTMLFormElement`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the `event.target.children`

`children` is an `HTMLCollection`, similar to an array. You can get values by its index `children[0]` or `chilren[1]`

Either you need to go over all your children or convert it to an array and find the desired component by its `name` or `id`

To convert you can just use the spread operator

```
const children = [...event.target.children]
const gameId = children.find(child => child.name === "gameId")?.value
```

**ANYWAY**

I would highly recommend having control over your fields and always having state management for them.
You can even use some libraries to manage your forms.

I prefer using `react-hook-form`, but you can choose anything you want